# Why is the text in the JPanel Clipping after a certain point?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

If we drag the scroll bar past a certain point the text displayed becomes "mushed." I manually placed the string at the far end to see if it can be displayed and it worked.

It draws fine from those coordinates when I manually set it (as in the example) but clips when I change the x-coordinate with the scroll bar).

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ScrollBarDemo2 extends JFrame {
private MessagePanel messagePanel = new MessagePanel();
private JScrollBar jscbHorizontal = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
private JScrollBar jscbVertical = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
private JTextField jtfMessage = new JTextField("Example String");

public ScrollBarDemo2() {
    // Add components to the frame
    add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jscbHorizontal, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jscbVertical, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(jtfMessage, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Register listener to scroll bars
    ScrollBarListener jscbListener = new ScrollBarListener();
    jscbHorizontal.addAdjustmentListener(jscbListener);
    jscbVertical.addAdjustmentListener(jscbListener);

    // Register a listener in text field
    jtfMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Set the text in messagePanel to the given text
            messagePanel.setText(e.getActionCommand());
        }
    });
}

private class ScrollBarListener implements AdjustmentListener {
    @Override
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        // Determine the orientation of the event source
        JScrollBar scrollBar = (JScrollBar)e.getAdjustable();

        if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL) {
            // Obtain the horizontal space remaining
            double spaceAvailable = (double)messagePanel.getHorizontalEmptySpace();

            // Find how much to scale each value of the scroll bars (since we're using the default 100 total values)
            double scaledValue = (scrollBar.getValue() * spaceAvailable / (double)scrollBar.getMaximum());

            // Set new x coordinate
            messagePanel.setX((int)scaledValue);
        }
        else if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == JScrollBar.VERTICAL) {
            // Obtain the vertical space remaining
            double spaceAvailable = (double)messagePanel.getVerticalEmptySpace();

            // Find how much to scale each value of the scroll bars (since we're using the default 100 total values)
            double scaledValue = (scrollBar.getValue() / (double)scrollBar.getMaximum()) * spaceAvailable;

            // Set new x coordinate
            messagePanel.setY((int)scaledValue);
        }
    }
}

/** main method **/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScrollBarDemo2 frame = new ScrollBarDemo2();
    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MessagePanel extends JPanel {
    private FontMetrics fm;
    private String message = "";
    private int messageX = -1;
    private int messageY = -1;

    public MessagePanel() {
        this("Welcome to Java");
    }

    public MessagePanel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        messageX += getWidth() / 50;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        messageX -= getWidth() / 50;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        messageY -= getHeight() / 100;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        messageY += getHeight() / 100;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getX() {
        return messageX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return messageY;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        messageX = x;
        repaint();

    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        messageY = y;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setText(String newMessage) {
        message = newMessage;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getVerticalEmptySpace() {
        return getHeight() - fm.getAscent();
    }

    public int getHorizontalEmptySpace() {
        return getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (messageX < 0 && messageY < 0) {     // Check to initialize centered position
            fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            messageX = getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(message); // Manually setting it to the very end coordinate
            messageY = getHeight() / 2 - fm.getAscent() / 2;
        }

        g.drawString(message, messageX, messageY);

    }
}
```

Comment: `Thank you so much for your answer and runnable code! ` - I gave you the solution to you problem. All you needed to do was rename the methods and you have runnable. We are not here to write the code for you only give you the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I understand but I was told to "accept" unfortunately we can only "accept" one even though you gave a perfectly concise and succinct answer that showed me exactly what I did wrong and what I need to look out for. I was not looking for someone to devote their expertise and time so I was simply overwhelmed by Gilbert's answer and wrote a "thanks" despite the comments guidelines saying not to. As always I am very grateful for you and the community here for the many great answers and code reviews to my questions.

Comment: `I was told to "accept" unfortunately we can only "accept" one even though you gave a perfectly concise and succinct answer that showed me exactly what I did wrong and what I need to look out for.` - well it would seem that is the answer you should be accepting. It was the first answer to point out the problem and provide a solution and you still haven't said thanks.  `As always I am very grateful for you and the community` - well normally you also take the time to thank everybody who makes a suggestion. And you didn't thank anybody on your first question you posted either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code.  Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Scroll Bar Test]

1. I formatted your code.
2. I enclosed your Swing code in a Runnable, so I could start your Swing application on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) using the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  Oracle and I insist that all Swing applications start on the Event Dispatch thread.
3. As camickr said in his answer, you accidentally overrode the getX, getY, setX, and setY methods of JPanel.  I renamed your methods.
4. I used the action listener of the underlying JTextField Document so that whatever you type in the JTextField gets drawn on the JPanel.

There is still a problem with your messageX being set to less than zero.  I'm leaving this problem for you to solve.

Here's the corrected code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class ScrollBarDemo2 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3189856074534869132L;

    private JScrollBar jscbHorizontal = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
    private JScrollBar jscbVertical = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);

    private JTextField jtfMessage = new JTextField("Example String");

    private MessagePanel messagePanel = new MessagePanel(jtfMessage.getText());

    public ScrollBarDemo2() {
        // Add components to the frame
        add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jscbHorizontal, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(jscbVertical, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(jtfMessage, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Register listener to scroll bars
        ScrollBarListener jscbListener = new ScrollBarListener();
        jscbHorizontal.addAdjustmentListener(jscbListener);
        jscbVertical.addAdjustmentListener(jscbListener);

        // Register a listener in text field
        jtfMessage.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                messagePanel.setText(jtfMessage.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                messagePanel.setText(jtfMessage.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                messagePanel.setText(jtfMessage.getText());
            }
        });

    }

    private class ScrollBarListener implements AdjustmentListener {
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            // Determine the orientation of the event source
            JScrollBar scrollBar = (JScrollBar) e.getAdjustable();

            if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL) {
                // Obtain the horizontal space remaining
                double spaceAvailable = (double) messagePanel
                        .getHorizontalEmptySpace();

                // Find how much to scale each value of the scroll bars (since
                // we're using the default 100 total values)
                double scaledValue = (scrollBar.getValue() * spaceAvailable / (double) scrollBar
                        .getMaximum());

                // Set new x coordinate
                messagePanel.setMessageX((int) scaledValue);
            } else if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == JScrollBar.VERTICAL) {
                // Obtain the vertical space remaining
                double spaceAvailable = (double) messagePanel
                        .getVerticalEmptySpace();

                // Find how much to scale each value of the scroll bars (since
                // we're using the default 100 total values)
                double scaledValue = (scrollBar.getValue() / (double) scrollBar
                        .getMaximum()) * spaceAvailable;

                // Set new x coordinate
                messagePanel.setMessageY((int) scaledValue);
            }
        }
    }

    /** main method **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollBarDemo2 frame = new ScrollBarDemo2();
                frame.setTitle("Scroll Bar Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class MessagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2743160276473942475L;

    private FontMetrics fm;
    private String message = "";
    private int messageX = -1;
    private int messageY = -1;

    public MessagePanel() {
        this("Welcome to Java");
    }

    public MessagePanel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        messageX += getWidth() / 50;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        messageX -= getWidth() / 50;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        messageY -= getHeight() / 100;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        messageY += getHeight() / 100;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getMessageX() {
        return messageX;
    }

    public int getMessageY() {
        return messageY;
    }

    public void setMessageX(int x) {
        messageX = x;
        repaint();

    }

    public void setMessageY(int y) {
        messageY = y;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setText(String newMessage) {
        message = newMessage;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getVerticalEmptySpace() {
        return getHeight() - fm.getAscent();
    }

    public int getHorizontalEmptySpace() {
        return getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (messageX < 0 && messageY < 0) { // Check to initialize centered
                                            // position
            fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            messageX = getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(message); // Manually setting
                                                                // it to the
                                                                // very end
                                                                // coordinate
            messageY = getHeight() / 2 - fm.getAscent() / 2;
        }

        g.drawString(message, messageX, messageY);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and runnable code!

Answer (score 1):

`getX()` and `getY` are methods of the `JComponent` class and you should not be overriding them.

Rename the methods, maybe something like getMessageX() and getMessageY(). You should also rename the setX() and setY() methods to be consistent with whatever getter names you choose.